# Lock free stack poor performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free

I'm using free-list structure for a while implemented as the sort of stack:

```
// gets the next free index from the top
unsigned acquire()
{
    std::lock_guard lock{m_spin};
    if (m_nextFreeHandle < m_size)
    {
        return std::exchange(m_nextFreeHandle, m_nextHandles[m_nextFreeHandle]);
    }
    return InvalidHandle;
} 

void release(unsigned handle) // returns the index to the list
{
    std::lock_guard lock{m_spin};
    m_nextHandles[handle] = std::exchange(m_nextFreeHandle, handle);
}
```

Thread safety guaranteed by using simple spinlock:

```
void SpinLock::lock() noexcept
{
    while (flag_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
        while (flag_.test(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

void SpinLock::unlock() noexcept
{
    flag_.clear(std::memory_order_release);
}
```

I decided to try rework it with lock-free approach:

```
static constexpr unsigned extractMark(unsigned value) noexcept
{
    return value >> 22;
}

static constexpr unsigned addMark(unsigned value, unsigned tag) noexcept
{
    return value | (tag << 22);
}

static constexpr unsigned clearMark(unsigned value) noexcept
{
    return value & (0xFFFFFFFFu >> 10);
}

unsigned acquire()
{
    auto nextIndex = m_nextFreeHandle.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if(clearMark(nextIndex)< m_size)
    {
        unsigned newNextIndex;
        do
        {
            newNextIndex = m_nextHandles[clearMark(nextIndex)].load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        } while (!m_nextFreeHandle.compare_exchange_weak(nextIndex, newNextIndex, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_acquire));
        
        auto mark = extractMark(nextIndex);
        nextIndex = addMark(clearMark(nextIndex), mark + 1); // to avoid ABA problem
        return nextIndex;
    }
    return InvalidIndex;
}
        
        
void release(unsigned handle)
{
    if(handle == InvalidIndex)
        return;
    auto currentHead = m_nextFreeHandle.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    do
    {
        m_nextHandles[clearMark(handle)].store(currentHead, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    while (!m_nextFreeHandle.compare_exchange_weak(currentHead, handle, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

Then I wrote simple test (single and multithreaded)

```
    tbb::parallel_for(0, 10'000'000, [&](int) {
        auto h0 = list.acquire();
        list.release(h0);
    });
```

and both times (single and multithreaded) lock free version is much slower than spinlock one!

I'd expect the lock free version to be at least as fast as spinlock, but it's like 1.5x times slower both for one and for 12 threads (I'm using Intel Core i5 11th gen with 6 cores and HT).
It's my first experience in writing lock free structures and I'm confused.
What I'm doing wrong? Am I expect too much from the lock-free approach or doing something not optimal way?

Comment: I have to ask, are you building your code with compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: The perpetual chase for the elusive lock-free unicorn fairy nearly always ends in a major disappointment.

Comment: *What I'm doing wrong?* -- Not telling us how you built your app, whether it is built using optimizations turned on or not.

Comment: Optimizations are turned on. I'm building the project using MS Visual Studio 2022, Release build with /O2 /Ob2 /Ot /GL

Comment: @FoxCanFly *It's my first experience in writing lock free structures and I'm confused.* -- Did you research or find any existing implementation that has good peformance?  Trying to do or learn this from scratch is not recommended -- attempt to learn from what's already out there.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but `std::lock_guard lock{m_spin};` doesn't exactly look like lock free to me. But then again I've not ventured much into the land of lock free programming. ;) I only take an effort in that direction when I have a proven performance bottleneck

Comment: @PepijnKramer The first code snippet is the "before" picture. the lock-free version is later.

Comment: I see you use `tbb::parallel_for`. Have you checked if [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) (or similar) with a parallel execution policy perhaps performs better?

Answer (score 1):

Lock-free algorithms are NOT guaranteed to be faster than lock-based algorithms. In highly-contended situations, they can easily be slower.

Since your code consists almost entirely of atomic reads, writes, and CASs, there's going to be a ton of work spent on ensuring cache coherence between the cores, transferring data and adjusting cache line states. No core will get to "own" `m_nextFreeHandle` for more than a few cycles. This is the worst case for lock-free algorithms.

In contrast, your lock-based approach has the effect of slowing down those contentions. After the first thread grabs the lock, the other threads will fail to acquire the lock a couple of times and then yield. Yielding involves a context switch, which will take many cycles to complete. Meanwhile, the first thread is actually getting work done, with an uncontended spinlock and an uncontended `m_nextFreeHandle`. Eventually it'll get sniped by some other core, and then it likewise will repeatedly yield while some other core gets work done.

In short, this is not a workload where having multiple cores is going to help, because all it involves is communicating between cores. Lock-free programming just makes that worse.

Comment: If the actual use-case is different from this benchmark (lower contention), lock-free might be fine, maybe even more efficient.  But yeah, benchmarking multiple threads all hammering on the shared data as fast as they can is the worst case, leading to many CAS retries and time spent waiting for cache lines to bounce between cores for every time one thread *does* succeed at making progress.  And yeah as you say, once some waiters go to sleep, a thread may be able to unlock + lock again and get a bunch of work done while cache lines stay hot on one CPU core.  Pretty unrealistic vs. most uses.

Comment: @PeterCordes But what exactly the case when lock free version will be more efficient than spinlock one? Any suggestions for test/benchmark?

Comment: @FoxCanFly: It might be hard to benchmark, but if you have threads do a significant amount of private work between interacting with shared data, you can measure how much total progress all threads make per unit time, hopefully stalling less from lock-free stacks if contention is low.  (So you're not measuring throughput of the lock-free data-structure, you're measuring the CPU throughput impact on the work you're doing between calls to these functions.)